# Even and odd elements in more general additive groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

My question is motivated by [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970343?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) in whose second page the author describes an analog of even and odd numbers for any additive group $G$ with a subgroup of index $2$, denoted $G^+$: the elements of this subgroup are called even elements and the elements of the complement, $G^-$, are called odd elements.

By additive group it is meant abelian, but I'm not sure if it must be cyclic.

The question is

> Is the sum of two odd elements always an even element?

I tried to prove it doing the same that I would do for the integers. Namely, given two odd integers I can write them as $2n+1$ and $2m+1$ respectively, so their sum equals $2(m+n+1)$.

The analogy I tried was considering the cosets $\{G^+, G^-\}$ and letting $h_1,h_2\in G^-$ such that $h_1+h_2\notin G^+$. I can write them as $h_1=h_1'+g_1$, $h_2=h_2'+g_2$, where $h'_i\in G^-$ and $g_i\in G^+$. Here, $g_1$ and $g_2$ play the role of $2n$ and $2m$, respectively. The problem is that I can't find an analog to the number $1$.

If I assume $G$ to be cyclic, say $G=\langle g\rangle $, it would suffice to show that $g+g\in G^+$. However, I haven't been able to prove it. Are there example of (cyclic or non-cyclic) groups with a subgroup of order $2$ in which the statement is false or can I prove it for some kind of group?

Comment: Do you know quotient groups?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I do. This would be the same as asking whether $h_1+h_2$ is trivial in the quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G^+$ has index $2$, $G/G^+$ is a group of order $2$, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, the non-identity element of $G/G^+$ is $G^-$, and thus in the quotient group $G^-+G^-=G^+$.

Now given any two odd elements $h_1,h_2$, we have
$$(h_1+h_2)+G^+=(h_1+G^+)+(h_2+G^+)=G^-+G^-=G^+,$$
hence $h_1+h_2\in G^+$.

Note that since a group of index $2$ is necessarily normal, this works even in a non-abelian group; in fact this is exactly what happens with the even and odd permutations in the symmetric groups.

---

This can also be proved without using quotient groups : if $h_1,h_2\in G^-$, then we also have $-h_1\in G^-$, as otherwise we would have $-h_1\in G^+$ and then $h_1\in G_+$. In particular, $h_2\in G^-=(-h_1)+G^+$, thus $h_2=-h_1+g$ for some $g\in G^+$; and then $h_1+h_2=g\in G^+$. Again, this works even if $G$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 3):

In fact you can even drop the assumption that the group is abelian.

The starting point is that a subgroup $G^+<G$ of index $2$ is always normal (this comes at once if you try to write down explicitely the partitions into right and left cosets).

Thus the quotient group $G/G^+$ exists and it has $2$ elements, and so is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

From this it follows immediately that a product $g_1g_2$ is in $G^+$ if and only if both or none of the $g_i$ are in $G^+$.